# iOS How to play audio from CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avcapturesession

I want to play audio directly from the microphone in iOS using Swift.
For this im using AVCaptureSession. Set my input device, output and delegate.
The delegate method: `captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)` is active.

But how can i get audio from the samplebuffer and play with AVAudioPlayer?

Maybe there is a much easier way to solve my problem?

I don't want to record any audio!!! 
"Only" capture and play via speakers.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I've been trying to find any information of how to do it for weeks, with no luck.